# Rows in <textarea> to links with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My script is here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg8Pu/3/)

i have two attributes in my form that my script do edit on a click in the div area/next to the link or double click on the link ( this how the script do the edit )

**my problem is**:  if i have a ***textarea*** that includes an URLs per row and it sums all the chars in one link, if you see my example above, the link below is actually textarea with ***test1.com*** in first row and ***test2.com*** in second row, **but** the script shows this link : ***test1.comtest2.com***, and i need it to be two link each one on a row, how can i do this ?

Comment: Please change the jsFiddle code to how you expect it to work. I see in your code that you have one <a> tag with "test1.com test2.com". This can only create ONE link.

Comment: Hi, that is a textarea and it has two links one per row, but it merge it to one link this is my problem

Comment: Are you putting the results from a query (ajax) into the textarea?

Comment: no, it's exactly like the demo above, i have a form with those inputs, the URL input can be editable by double click on the link, and the text area when i put 2 links (www.test1.com and www.test2.com) one per row, it merges it to one link by my script , and i want to change it some how to make the two link separately

Comment: Ahh i found it now. I would first recommend changing the way you allow editing of the links. It is not obvious to the user to dbl-click the part around the link to change the link. I will put a small example of a better option.

Comment: @Abude: Refer my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250567/500725)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/pg8Pu/12/)**

Addition to my previous answer, I have modified some parts of JQuery to handle your criteria.

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Date: </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <span id="status0" style="float:right;"/>2012-06-20
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*Anchor Text </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dasdas" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'anchor_text',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="anchor_text0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*URL </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <div style="padding:0 !important">
                    <div class="a0" style="padding:0 !important">
                        <a href="test1.com">test.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" value="dsad.cas" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" id="url0" style="display:none"/>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Address </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dsada" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'address',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="address0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Phone </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="432423" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'phone_number',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="phone_number0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Date: </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <span id="status4" style="float:right;"/>2012-06-22
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*Anchor Text </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dasdasd" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'anchor_text',4,'am','30')" class="mandatory4" readonly="readonly" id="anchor_text4"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left" style="vertical-align: top">
                <label>*URL </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <div style="padding:0 !important;">
                    <div class="a0" style="padding: 0px ! important; display: block;width:200px;">
                        <a target="_blank" href="test1.com">test1.com</a><br/>
                        <a target="_blank" href="test2.com">test2.com</a><br/>
                    </div>
                    <textarea cols="82" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',4,'am','30');$(this).autoGrow();" class="mandatory4" id="url4" input="" style="height: auto; overflow: hidden; display: none;" rows="3">test1.com<br></br>test2.com<br></br></textarea>
                    <div class="clear">
        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

### JQuery:

```
$('.a0 a').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Redirect only after 500 milliseconds
    if (!$(this).data('timer')) {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            window.open(href, '_blank')
        }, 500));
    }
    return false; // Prevent default action (redirecting)
});

$('.a0').dblclick(function(){
    var txt = document.createElement('div');
    $.each($(this).find('a'), function(i, val) {
        clearTimeout($(val).data('timer'));
        $(val).data('timer', null);
        $(txt).append($(val).text()); 
        $("<br>").appendTo(txt);
    });
    var content = $(this).parent().find('input,textarea');
    var text = "";
    $.each($(txt).html().split("<br>"), function(i, val) {
        if (val != "")
            text += val + "\n"; 
    });
    $(content).html(text);
    $(this).hide();
    $(content).show().focus();
})


$('#url0, #url1, #url4').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            $(this).show();
        else
        {
            var ele = this;
            var lines = $(ele).val().split("\n");
            var divEle = $(ele).hide().prev().show().empty();
            $.each(lines, function(i, val) {
                $("<a />").html(val).attr({
                    'href': val, 
                    'target': '_blank'}).appendTo(divEle);
                $("<br/>").appendTo(divEle);
            });
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: thanks a lot for all your efforts Siva, almost perfect : two thing still needs to be fixed, first, one you click on the `div` area should also edit the link, and second, i've seen a small bug, if you double click on the link it edits it correctly then if double click on it second time to modify it, then the edit won't work and will take you to the page, can you please fix those last thing?

Comment: @Abude: Follow these 2 steps:-
To edit the hyperlink, double click on dotted area (not on the hyperlink), 
To open the link, click on the link.

Comment: Siva, Thanks a lot for all your help , i accepted your answer:) please up vote the question if you can. thanks! we will keep in touch for future questions if u want...

Comment: Siva, i gave you the bounty too :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a string with white-space separated values:

```
var str = "test1.com test2.com";
```

you can retrieve the individual values by splitting it:

```
var vals = str.split(/\s+/);
```

The above uses a regex to split wherever there are one or more whitespace characters together, and will set `vals` to an array containing the values.

Your current code is really tied in to a single anchor element, so you'd need to update it to create however many are needed. Maybe if you wrapped your existing anchor in some container (a span or div) so that that container can hold multiple anchors then you could do something like this:

```
var vals = this.value.split(/\s+/),
    $container = $(this).hide().prev().show().empty();

$.each(vals, function(i, val) {
    if (i > 0) $("<span> </span>").appendTo($container);
    $("<a />").html(val).attr('href',val).appendTo($container);
});
```

Of course you need a corresponding change in the code that takes the anchor text and puts it in the textarea for editing, but I've done that in this **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/pg8Pu/4/

Comment: it's perfect! thanks a lot, can you please adjust it with the if,else case in my script, be cause i need it, if i don't have that, i will have the problem of disappear my input if it's empty.

Comment: resolved it, but can you help me with : when i add a link won't take the path it takes www.mywebsite/test1.com , how can i resolve this?

Comment: and oh, there's another bug, when i proceed this from the main form to this result in the cart. the link is also merged unless i edit the field in this final step of the order then it will break it in rows, so how i add your code not only to the .blur() ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to look at this any more today/tonight, but regarding your second comment about how it is treating the url as a relative path and doing `www.mywebsite/test1.com` instead of `test1.com`: in the code that sets the `href` attribute check whether the url already begins with `http://` or `https://` and if not add `http://`. E.g. (within the code from my question) `.attr('href',/^https?:\/\//.test(val) ? val : 'http://' + val)`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the URL problem, the only big problem now, that if you edit the textarea to look like links then hit run/update again on jsfiddle, won't save the changes, it doesn't keep them, for input i added `.attr('href',this.value);` PS: now, it saves the text, but it keeps it input[text] not link style so it show test1.comtest2.com and i edit it to test11.com test22.com and after refresh it looks test11.comtest22.com, not links, for this what can i do? thanks a lot again!

Comment: i mean maybe textera to be formatted as linked onload not just after editing, can we do this ?

Comment: please, i really need your help, i just need that split to be done not only when you click on the textarea but also from the beginning of the load page, because initially the data are pushed from another form where the textarea data are one per row so it should be displayed on that page you made the script for, one per row. thanks a lot bro!

Comment: i tried to put `.trigger('blur')` on the last and it works but now the timer double click won't just edit but will take me to the page and i don't want that for doubleclick. any other ideas ?

Comment: i added bounty for the question, can you help now please ?

Comment: can you please help me with this last thing? i would appreciate it very much, i will give you the bounty, just need you to help me with this. i think is very small thing to do, but i can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
$('#url0, #url1,#url4').each(

    function(index, element){

        $(element).blur(function(){

             l = this.value.split(/\s+/);

             $(this).hide().prev().show().empty();

             txt = "";

             for(var i in l) {

                 txt += '<a href="'+l[i] +'">'+l[i] + '</a><br />';

             }

             $(this).parent().find('div').not('.clear').html(txt);

        })
    }    
);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4LjW/)

Comment: it doesn't work really good, if you double click on the link to edit it and then click out it supplies the links with a double of it: for test1.com test2.com becomes test1.comtest1.comtest2.comtest2.com. can you check please ? or maybe help me with my last comment on the other answer ...

Comment: @Abude, Hi, i've edited the answer, by the way you need to update the a0 click function like suggested by nnnnnn, : `$('.a0').click(function(){
           $(this).parent().find('input,textarea').val($.map($(this).find('a'),function(el){return $(el).text();}).join(" ")).show().focus();
    $(this).hide();
})`

Comment: thanks man, can you invite me to a chat room to explain more, because it's just a simple thing to add that i can't figure it out

Comment: @Abude i'm sorry but now i'm away. basically the a0 function updated put a space between the words and then the blur process proceed to split... i can't chat now because i respond via iphone and chat is more difficult :-(

Comment: ohh i see, thanks a lot for all the efforts, my problem is that i want this split to be made not just when edit the link but also on the load of page to be in the right format with that split when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Abude, updated answer, see fiddle, i'm not sure if is what you want. Fiddle at this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4LjW/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update :) , i up-voted you, maybe you can do the same for my question :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/pg8Pu/11/)**

I have come across some of issues on `HTML` such as not closing `<br>`, `<input>` .. tags. Whatever I have seen issues on HTML, those I have fixed.

While testing the live demo, follow the steps:-

1. To edit the hyperlink, double click on dotted area
2. To open the link, click on the link

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Date: </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <span id="status0" style="float:right;"/>2012-06-20
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*Anchor Text </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dasdas" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'anchor_text',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="anchor_text0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*URL </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <div style="padding:0 !important">
                    <div class="a0" style="padding:0 !important">
                        <a href="test1.com">test.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" value="dsad.cas" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" id="url0" style="display:none"/>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Address </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dsada" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'address',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="address0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Phone </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="432423" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'phone_number',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" readonly="readonly" id="phone_number0"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>Date: </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <span id="status4" style="float:right;"/>2012-06-22
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <label>*Anchor Text </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <input type="text" value="dasdasd" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'anchor_text',4,'am','30')" class="mandatory4" readonly="readonly" id="anchor_text4"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left" style="vertical-align: top">
                <label>*URL </label>
            </td>
            <td class="cartRight">
                <div style="padding:0 !important;">
                    <div class="a0" style="padding: 0px ! important; display: block;width:200px;">
                        <a target="_blank" href="test1.comtest2.com">test1.com test2.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <textarea cols="82" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',4,'am','30');$(this).autoGrow();" class="mandatory4" id="url4" input="" style="height: auto; overflow: hidden; display: none;" rows="3">test1.com test2.com</textarea>
                    <div class="clear">
        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

### JS:

```
$('.a0 a').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Redirect only after 500 milliseconds
    if (!$(this).data('timer')) {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            window.open(href, '_blank')
        }, 500));
    }
    return false; // Prevent default action (redirecting)
});

$('.a0').dblclick(function(){
    var txt = "";
    for(var i=0; i<$(this).find('a').length; i++) {
        clearTimeout($(this).find('a').data('timer'));
        $(this).find('a').data('timer', null);
        txt += $(this).find('a').text() + "<br/>"; 
    }

    $(this).parent().find('input,textarea').html(txt).show().focus();
    $(this).hide();
})


$('#url0, #url1, #url4').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            $(this).show();
        else
        {
            var ele = this;
            var lines = $(ele).val().split("\n");
            var divEle = $(ele).hide().prev().show().empty();
            $.each(lines, function(i, val) {
                $("<a />").html(val).attr({
                    'href': val, 
                    'target': '_blank'}).appendTo(divEle);
                $("<br/>").appendTo(divEle);
            });
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to this question Siva, but some issues of the demo are: the second URL Field is a textarea that will include one text by row and now for example is merged in not a good way `test1.com%20test2.com`, should be `test1.com` space/newline `test2.com`, also need need double click to edit that input also when you double click on the link not just the `div`and one click to the `div` should also make edit.

Comment: here is the last update of the script and there's a small thing that is not working, see if you can fix it please and the answers are yours... thanks a lot ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242349/how-to-fix-my-jquery-bug

Comment: @Abude: I have added another **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11253961/500725)**. Check this.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are saving back whole text from `textarea` to url of one single `a` tag.
obviously it will remove the CR/LF from your text when using html() to read the value as CR/LF is not important in html.

If you need to have two tags you need to change your function and put a div instead of a tag as container and then in double click of any of your links read container text.
when saving back the textarea text as links, you need to create one single link (`a`) tag and put in container div

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you make a working demo in jsfiddle please so i can see that's working ?