# how to fix my JQuery bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The script is on jsfiddle here : [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/abude/kmhEQ/1/)

**What it does at the moment**: it's a form that have two types of URL field textarea and input, it converts the texts in those fields to a link to be click-able.

**How it works:** if you click next to the link/links you can edit the link or on a double click on the link. **IF** you click once on the link it takes you to that page.

**Last update:** i added the `.trigger('blur');` on the last line, **Because** before i did that, the text area was showing the links like one merged link, **for example** : `test.com` and `test2.com` were showing `test.comtest2.com`, after i added this last update, the split for textera work also on the load of page not just on the edit of textarea ( it was working without the last update but only when you edit the textarea and put between links a space, and i want it to be working on the load of page because the textarea format was sent already as one link pre row ).

**My problem:** after i did this last update, the double click is messed up, it should just be able to edit the link and don't go to that page unless one click, **but** now it edits it and in like one second it goes also to that page. **I want** the double click just to edit without going to that page. and to go only with one click.

Thanks a lot in advance!

The code also here:

`$('.a0 a').click(function(){`

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');

// Redirect only after 500 milliseconds
if (!$(this).data('timer')) {
   $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
      window.open(href, '_blank')
   }, 500));
}
return false; // Prevent default action (redirecting)});

$('.a0').dblclick(function(){
clearTimeout($(this).find('a').data('timer'));
$(this).find('a').data('timer', null);

$(this).parent().find('input,textarea').val($(this).find('a').text()).show().focus();
$(this).hide();})

$('.a0').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('input,textarea').val($.map($(this).find('a'),function(el){return $(el).text();}).join(" ")).show().focus();
$(this).hide();})

$('#url0, #url1,#url4').each(
function(index, element){
    $(element).blur(function(){
            var vals = this.value.split(/\s+/),
    $container = $(this).hide().prev().show().empty();

$.each(vals, function(i, val) {
    if (i > 0) $("<span><br /></span>").appendTo($container);
    $("<a />").html(val).attr('href',/^https?:\/\//.test(val) ? val : 'http://' + val).appendTo($container);;
});  })
}).trigger('blur');
```

Comment: Mixing single-click and double-click on the web is a design doomed to failure. Even if you could get it to work tolerably well, it's a usability disaster.

Comment: but it was working very good, i just wanted to make the textarea to work good for links, and after i added the `trigger()` worked the textarea but the doubleclick is not working good now...

Comment: No, it's not going to work.  It'll be even worse for people using tablets/phones.

Comment: @Pointy, no, it was working really fine with that timer and worked fine for click and dbclick, but the trigger() breaks that work ... ok let's try it other way, that last part of the script does the split for textarea to make one link per row, but it does only on edit action, how can i make that split to be done onload of the page?thanks

Comment: Do what you want; I'm just conveying the generally accepted wisdom and best practice from the world of professional web application design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double-click is always predeeded by the following chain of events:

mousedown, mouseup, *click*, mousedown, mouseup, *click*, **dblclick**

You can make your click-events wait and check if a double-click event happened afterwards. [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is your friend. Be sure to copy any data you need from the `event` object passed to your handler. That object is destroyed after the handler finished - which is *before* your delayed handler is invoked.

---

You can manually dispatch a double click event to prevent click-events from being executed prior to them. [See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ3YP/)

```
// ms to wait for a doubleclick
var doubleClickThreshold = 300;
// timeout container
var clickTimeout;
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
    var that = this;
    var event;

    if (clickTimeout) {
        try {
            clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
        } catch(x) {};

        clickTimeout = null;
        handleDoubleClick.call(that, e);
        return;
    }

    // the original event object is destroyed after the handler finished
    // so we'll just copy over the data we might need. Skip this, if you
    // don't access the event object at all.
    event = $.extend(true, {}, e);
    // delay click event
    clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        clickTimeout = null;
        handleClick.call(that, event);
    }, doubleClickThreshold);

});

function handleClick(e) {
    // Note that you cannot use event.stopPropagation(); et al,
    // they wouldn't have any effect, since the actual event handler
    // has already returned
    console.log("click", this, e);
    alert("click");
}

function handleDoubleClick(e) {
    // this handler executes synchronously with the actual event handler,
    // so event.stopPropagation(); et al can be used!
    console.log("doubleclick", this, e);
    alert("doubleclick");
}
```

Comment: can you please make a demo on jsfiddle to see exactly if your answer work like i want it? thanks !

Comment: I'll have to get back to you tonight. leaving for a meeting now. sorry. General idea is quite simple, so someone should be able to give you some demo code…

Comment: ok, sure, please get back to me, because i see nobody is answering and i have no idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks a lot for the code, but i'm not really good with jquery and i couldn't figure out how to implement you code to work with my code, can you please make a fork in jsfiddle to my code and add your code there to see if it works? thanks a lot!

Comment: please help me if you can with this, because i can't figure it out .. thanks a lot rodneyrehm

Comment: Your fiddle is using jQuery 1.2.6 - no wonder my example won't work there. Is there a reason why you need a decade(!) old version of jQuery, or did you just roll the dice on which version to select?

Comment: no, unfortunately i can't change the version of the JQuery :(

Comment: but isn't any method that can resolve this issue on my version ? :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYdU/1/ - you should seriously upgrade to a current version, though.

Comment: waw, it almost perfect, really many thanks, just needs one more thing please, can you make on one click on the `div` area ( next to the link ) also to edit ? thanks a lot!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYdU/2/ - wasn't really hard, try that stuff your self first, next time ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, it's great, i will accept your answer right now, we will keep in touch for future question if you would like so :) thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi man, i have a small bug on the script, on my page, when i click first time on the link it does the edit, after that works fine = click and it goes to the page, but first time it does the edit stuff, i want not just `blur` with this `.trigger('blur')` but also at the beginning , do you get my bug? please help me. thanks a lot !

Comment: rodneyrehm if you want i can make a new question, but please help me because i really need it :(

Comment: extract the code worrying you into a new fiddle and pose a new question. In that question, note what you've tried already.

Comment: the code is the exact code of yours, my problem is that when i click first time on the link it does the edit and after that everything works great, and i thing because the click action is only `trigger('blur')` and maybe needs to be from the load or something ... http://jsfiddle.net/xEYdU/2/ ... thanks, do you want me to make a new question ?

Comment: I seriously do not understand the problem.

Comment: :) sorry if i didn't choose more specific words; ok, when you click ,one click, for the first time on the link, it should go to the page, right? ok, on my page when you click ,one click, first time it makes the edit action, not going to the page, after i click out(blur) and then click again ,one click, on the link, it goes to the page perfect, so i just want the trigger to be made not just for the blur but also from the beginning, do you get my issue now ? thanks!

Comment: the first click opens the page rather than the edit-box. At least that's how Firefox 13, Chrome and Safari do it.

Comment: yes, in myfiddle is working fine, but on my page for some rezones i don't know isn't working, so i thought to add trigger to onload or some method to make push it or make priority, can't we?

Comment: here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307576/need-the-script-to-be-called-for-onload-too-not-just-on-blur

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle refuses to load on my connection for some reason, so cant see the code. 
Based on your explanation i suggest you look into [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to add more control on what should happen on your click events. This could be used in conjunction with @rodneyrehm's answer.

Comment: i updated the answer with the code because jsfiddle isn't working, thanks a lot for the note

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my previous **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253961/500725)**.

For your quick reference, I have pasted my answer here

```
$('.a0 a').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Redirect only after 500 milliseconds
    if (!$(this).data('timer')) {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            window.open(href, '_blank')
        }, 500));
    }
    return false; // Prevent default action (redirecting)
});

$('.a0').dblclick(function(){
    var txt = document.createElement('div');
    $.each($(this).find('a'), function(i, val) {
        clearTimeout($(val).data('timer'));
        $(val).data('timer', null);
        $(txt).append($(val).text()); 
        $("<br>").appendTo(txt);
    });
    var content = $(this).parent().find('input,textarea');
    var text = "";
    $.each($(txt).html().split("<br>"), function(i, val) {
        if (val != "")
            text += val + "\n"; 
    });
    $(content).html(text);
    $(this).hide();
    $(content).show().focus();
})


$('#url0, #url1, #url4').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            $(this).show();
        else
        {
            var ele = this;
            var lines = $(ele).val().split("\n");
            var divEle = $(ele).hide().prev().show().empty();
            $.each(lines, function(i, val) {
                $("<a />").html(val).attr({
                    'href': val, 
                    'target': '_blank'}).appendTo(divEle);
                $("<br/>").appendTo(divEle);
            });
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: you are aware of the fact that each blur() event kills and re-creates all the `<a>` in `.a0`? Because of that the click-handler you register in line 1 is not present anymore (on the newly created elements). So after you edited a link block once, you won't be able to doubleclick a link again.

Comment: I saw your code/demo, which is why I commented in the first place.