# need the script to be called for "onload" too not just on "blur"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#url0, #url1, #url2, #url3, #url4, #url5, #url6, #url7, #url8, #url9, #url10').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).blur(function() {
        var vals = this.value.split(/\s+/);
        var $container = $(this).hide().prev().show().empty();

        $.each(vals, function(i, val) {
            if (i > 0) {
                $("<span> </span>").appendTo($container);
            }

            $("<a />")
                .html(val)
                .attr('href',/^https?:\/\//.test(val) ? val : 'http://' + val)
                .appendTo($container)
                .click(handleClickEvent);
        });
    });
}).trigger('blur');

// ms to wait for a doubleclick
var doubleClickThreshold = 300;
// timeout container
var clickTimeout;

$('.aCustomDiv a').click(handleClickEvent);
$('.aCustomDiv').click(handleDivClick);

function handleClickEvent(e) {
    var that = this;
    var event;

    if (clickTimeout) {
        try {
 clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
        } catch(x) {};

        clickTimeout = null;
        handleDoubleClick.call(that, e);
        return false;
    }

    clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        clickTimeout = null;
        handleClick.call(that, event);
    }, doubleClickThreshold);

    return false;
}

function handleDivClick(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parent()
        .find('input,textarea')
        .show()
        .focus();
    $this.hide();
}

function handleDoubleClick(e) {
    var $this = $(this).parent();
 $this.parent()
        .find('input,textarea')
        //.val($a.text())
        .show()
        .focus();
    $this.hide();
}

function handleClick(e) {
    window.open(this.href, '_blank')
}
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div style="padding:0 !important;margin-top:8px !important;">
<div class="aCustomDiv" style="padding: 0px ! important; display: block;">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a><span></span><a href="http://www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a><span></span><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">www.wikipedia.org</a>
</div>
<input type="text" value="www.google.com www.facebook.com www.wikipedia.org" onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',0,'pr','35')" class="mandatory0" id="url0" style="display: none;" readonly="readonly">
```

this script does the following:

1. converts the text to url for those ids (url0 ...)
2. double click on the link makes it editable
3. one click on the div area, next to link makes it editable
4. one click on the link => goes to the page

**my problem** : for some reason i don't know, the one click on the link doesn't go to the page but edits it, only the FIRST time , after that works great, so i want the first function to be called also onload not only when blur. how can i do this ?

Comment: Does this happen in a specific browser? Because your code is already wrapped in a DOMReady callback and works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xEYdU/2/

Comment: no, it does that in all the browsers, firefox, chrome, .. etc

Comment: It also works fine in the fiddle created from the code you provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/5XBRj/

Comment: i know it works fine in the fiddle, but for some reason on my page doesn't work, and i was wondering if there's another solution, maybe trigger the onload or something

Comment: Dude, if it works in the fiddle but doesn't work on your page, there's got to be something wrong with your page. you know, the parts you DID NOT post here. How is anyone supposed to *guess* what could be screwing things up for you?

Comment: i know you are absolutely right, i just have an ajax edit inline on the input that i didn't post here, every thing else i posted. i just wanted to know can't we trigger the onload or something to make priority ?

Comment: (a) you are already binding to the DOMReady event (happening long before the load event). (b) you don't trigger any of these events as these events are triggered by the browser to inform you about state changes. (c) the blur event is already executed for all your input elements in line 19 of your code.

Comment: @rodneyrehm Hi again! i tried everything to make it work as in jsfiddle but it's not working, and it's the exact same code. i removed even the ajax inline edit `onchange="immediateEditItemInCart(this.value,'url',0,'pr','35')"` really don't know, what to do? can you create a chat room so we can talk more there please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as loading on startup, javascript is single threaded so just firing a method will work if you keep things in order (... just add a couple of parens).  But because you are trying to access the DOM you do want to wait for the elements to be available (otherwise you will get nothing back from a selector).

But you do already have:

```
$(document).ready( function(){} );
```

Which does exactly what you are asking for, it also has a shorthand of:

```
$( function(){} );
```

So I would have to agree with rodneyrehm that is it probably some collision that you have with other js on your page.  You might want to encapsulate it a bit in some namespace to make sure that is the not the problem.

I wrote up a quick version that should get your on your way as a starting point if you are still having problems: http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/dUWwB/.  I pulled the 'updateURL ' method out in case your ajax call (you mentioned) was just pre-populating the field (that way you could pass in the value also).

It also works with multiple inputs/displays which is what I think you were going for was not 100% sure.